# Render Views from outside the Views folder in Lumen

Tags: laravel-5, lumen, api-doc, fastroute

i'm writing an API in Lumen 5.3 and i'd like to include [APIDoc](http://apidocjs.com/) for my Documentation, im rendering the APIDoc files to app/API/Docs and i'd like to be able to render the index.html from this file whenever the /docs route is hit by a Get request on the browser. How can i achieve this in Lumen?

Answer (score 0):

The way i ended up fixing it was i just moved everything over to the public folder under public/docs and then set my apidoc script up in npm so that it'll copy it's files to that directory when i run `npm run apidoc`

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "apidoc": "apidoc -i app/API/v1/Controllers/ -o public/docs/"
},
```

Then in my routes file i set up a `file_get_contents` for the index page of the docs.

```
return file_get_contents( public_path() . 'docs/index.html');
```

And it works just fine.